# output PostgreSQL query result as JSON encoded binary for Django Response

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I'm pulling 1M+ rows of data out of my database to send to a HTTP client.

The PostgreSQL query returns JSON formatted data.

I would like to pass the JSON directly to the Response, without casting to Python objects in between, which takes a LOT of memory:

Uncompressed JSON string is about 150Mb. When profiling memory before and after fetching the data, I get a diff of ~1Gb.

If I cast as text, I see something more in the order of 250Mb, which I could live with.

When I output the data using the Postgres `to_json`, I do get a JSON object, but it is being parsed by `psycopg2` into a Python object, and it takes the huge amount of memory cited.

If I cast the JSON to a string within the SQL (using `to_json(result)::text` I end up with a string but the `"` get escaped: when feeding this to the Response object, it ends up sending a string, and the client receives a string, which despite the `application/json` header does not get parsed as JSON. I want to pass JSON, and not have to parse it on the client (let the browser do this)

The Response class seems to parse the JSON object data into binary, encoded with a charset. It all makes sense, and it seems like I need to get a binary object rather than a string to pass to the Response directly.

How could I get a binary encoded result out of Postgres directly?

Comment: What about `to_json(result)::bytea`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I wished it'd been that simple, but I'm getting `cannot cast type record to bytea`

Comment: i tried `(to_json(result)::text)::bytea` and I get a result but it is still a python `tuple` :-(